# how to remove double strings with sed grep awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep

hello how to remove and clear output ?

**test.txt**

```
http://urlcom/longStringxyzABC**|**http://urlcom/longStringxyzABC
```

i want, `|` including character deletion after

i want result

```
http://urlcom/longStringxyzABC
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/|.*//' test.txt

grep -oP '.*?(?=\|)' test.txt

awk -F'|' '{print $1}' test.txt
```

Comment: `grep -o` outputs both (in general all) matches, which is not desired here.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 oops good catch, I've amended using PCRE but please feel free to suggest a better alternative